# Is it possible to change the iphone date picker?

Tags: iphone, calendar

I'm new to apple products, just got a new iPhone 7.
I've been an avid GNU/Linux and Android, but decided to give iOS a chance.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the phone calendar picker (looks like a roulette wheel) to a calendar grid.

I'm looking for a way to change the date picker of *existing* applications, such as Gmail and Safari, *e.g.*, by activating/deactivating a setting configuration or tweaking the application.

Precisely, I want to change from this:
[image: ios date picker]

to this:
[image: android date picker]

Answer (score 2):

An individual application could present their own date picker if it were programmed that way. You cannot change the applications made by other people.

A jailbreak tweak could potentially try to make this change, but I do not know of any.

If you are looking to make your own application, I would recommend asking in the regular Stack Overflow.